# Laravel 8 Factory Migration fails on n + 1 iteration

Tags: laravel, factory, seed

Not sure what is happening here. I have a table called `news` as follows:

```
Schema::create('news', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('featured_img');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->enum('audience', ['all', 'users', 'customers', 'residents', 'plumbers'])->default('users');
    $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('featured_from')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('featured_to')->nullable();

    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('customer_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('customers');
});
```

I have a factory for `news`:

```
class NewsFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = News::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $audience = [
            'all', 'users', 'customers', 'residents', 'plumbers',
        ];

        $img = [
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1492724441997-5dc865305da7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1679&q=80',
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547586696-ea22b4d4235d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1679&q=80',
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496128858413-b36217c2ce36?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1679&q=80',
        ];

        $date = now()->subMonths(rand(1, 20));

        $randAudience = $audience[array_rand($audience)];
        $randImg = $img[array_rand($img)];
        $customer = Customer::where('parent_id', 1)->orWhereNull('parent_id')->inRandomOrder()->first();

        echo "c => " . $randAudience . "\n";

        return [
            'customer_id' => $customer->id,
            'audience' => $randAudience,
            'private_customer_id' => null,
            'title' => $this->faker->title,
            'body' => $this->faker->realText,
            'featured_img' => $randImg,
            'published_at' => $date,
            'featured_from' => $date,
            'featured_to' => $date->addDays(14),
        ];
    }
}
```

I then call it in a seeder like this:

```
public function run()
{
    News::factory()
        ->count(3)
        ->create();
}
```

It shows me it runs the 3 times, then seems to fail on the fourth iteration (?) with the following error:

```
c => residents
c => all
c => users
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23514]: Check violation: 7 ERROR:  new row for relation "news" violates check constraint "news_audience_check"
```

Any help is appreciated

**UPDATE**: From the Postgresql console, the `\d news` output per @IGP suggestion. The check is the `ENUM` validation.

```
Check constraints:
    "news_audience_check" CHECK (audience::text = ANY (ARRAY['all'::character varying, 'users'::character varying, 'customers'::character varying, 'residents'::character varying, 'plumbers'::character varying]::text[]))
```

Additionally, if I comment out the random assignment of an audience value (and allow the default to be set) then it works.

```
// 'audience' => $randAudience,
```

Using a random value it triggers the check on n+1 iteration (why a 4th iteration when I asked for 3 instances?). Also, the error dump (below) shows the `audience` column of n+1 record to contain `residents` which is a valid entry.

```
    SQLSTATE[23514]: Check violation: 7 ERROR:  new row for relation "news" violates check constraint "news_audience_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, b9f00221-49f8-4d92-9813-026206e6aa76, 2, Mr., https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547586696-ea22b4d4235d?ixlib=..., Mouse. '--I proceed. "Edwin and Morcar, the earls of Mercia and ..., "residents", null, 2020-10-23 23:35:58, 2020-10-23 23:35:58, 2020-10-23 23:35:58, 1, 1, null, 2021-01-09 23:35:59, 2021-01-09 23:35:59). (SQL: insert into "news" ("customer_id", "audience", "private_customer_id", "title", "body", "featured_img", "published_at", "featured_from", "featured_to", "uuid", "creator_id", "updater_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (2, "residents", ?, Mr., Mouse. '--I proceed. "Edwin and Morcar, the earls of Mercia and Northumbria, declared for him: and even Stigand, the patriotic archbishop of Canterbury, found it advisable--"' 'Found WHAT?' said the., https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547586696-ea22b4d4235d?ixlib=rb-.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1679&q=80, 2020-10-23 23:35:58, 2020-10-23 23:35:58, 2020-10-23 23:35:58, b9f00221-49f8-4d92-9813-026206e6aa76, 1, 1, 2021-01-09 23:35:59, 2021-01-09 23:35:59) returning "id")
```

Comment: What is the `news_audience_check` constraint?

Comment: I can only think it is the `ENUM` validation on `audience` column?

Comment: Maybe but what is it? What is the rule? is it defined in your migration for the `news` table?

Comment: Hi no, there is no rule. The migration for news is on the post. So I do not understand why it shows 3 created OK, then fails on #4 with this issue, when I only asked for 3 items.

Comment: There is a rule. Maybe it's not in your migrations. If you're using mysql can you check the result of the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE news` ? Or the `CREATE code` for that table in your database administration tool if you're using one

Comment: But I am using Podtgresql and the query to create the table is above.

Comment: Do you have a mutator in your model? (setAudienceAttribute). What does the rest of the error says? It should throw something like 'Failing row contains.....(....) (SQL: insert into 'news' ....)

Comment: The constraint I was talking about can be seen if you go into the postgres console and run \d news. Your code generates [this constraint](https://i.ibb.co/DG9svKp/imagen.png). I think you have a mutator changing the audience's value because I copied your code and had no problem creating 1000 news with your factory (had to eliminate the private_customer_id line since it wasn't in the migration). Or maybe audience is not in your fillable properties.

Comment: Hi @IGP I just added the output of `\d` to the post. And it points to the `ENUM` validation.

Comment: Yes, but have you checked your model? I tested your code on a fresh install and had no problem. Do you have a mutator for the `audience` attribute? Is the `audience` attribute in your `$fillable` array?

Comment: If you ask for 4 does it fail on 5?

Comment: Yes. Weird. The model definitely does not have any mutators for the affected field. So I do not know. I have executed the seeds without factory and it worked.